# USB on/off switch

Tags: usb, led-strip, toggle-switch

I have this LED light strip which has AA Battery converter with a USB female output port. I will attach picture below. I would like to know how can I connect a SPST on/off switch to the light strip so that I can easily turn the lights on and off. Do I just tap into one of the power wires in the USB cord?
Thanks for any advice.

[image: LED light strip]
[image: switch]

Comment: Yes ... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @brhans thank you.. so just tap into the single red/orange +5v power wire and bridge that wire with the switch? do i need to add any fuses or anything? what is the recommend wire gauge size, also do all the wires have to be the same gauge?

Comment: You'll want to tap into the (hopefully) red wire (5V DC) that's inside one the black USB cables.  The blue/red/green/black ribbon cable probably (often) has 12V on the black wire with ground being pulse width modulated on the other wires.  For the switch polarity doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can splice in-between the battery pack and the female usb plug or the usb male plug and that black rectangle. Either the V+ or the Ground (unless both the shield and ground are tied together). Color is not guaranteed so make sure you use a multimeter to figure out which is which.

Personally I would add the switch to the case if you can.

No added fuse is needed. And for this you could probably use 24 or 22 awg. It may be thicker than whats already used.

Comment: thank you for this information